# how to clean my script?

Tags: bash, scripting

It makes what it is suppose to make, but I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient/clever solution to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -iname "*.mp4" | while read f
do

    id=$(echo $f | sed -n 's/.*.S\([0-9]\+\)E\([0-9]\+\)..*/\1x\2/p' | sed 's/^0*//')

    if [ -z "$id" ]; then
    echo "Warning! there's no match for $f"
    else
        srt=(*$id*)
        newName=$(echo $srt | sed 's/ (English).srt/.mp4/g')
        mv "$f" "$newName"
    fi

done
```

This first part takes the name of the srt file and rename the mp4 file.

```
for i in *" (Español (España)).srt"
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "${i%%" (Español (España)).srt"}.esp.srt"
done
sleep 0.5
for i in *".srt"
do
  rm *" (Español (España)).srt"
done
```

The above piece of code, change the encoding for srt files

```
for i in *".mp4"
do
  i=${i%.mp4} 
  mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" \
  "--language" "1:eng" \
  "-a" "1" "-d" "0" "-S" "-T" "$i.mp4" \
  "--language" "0:eng" \
  "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "$i (English).srt" \
  "--language" "0:spa" \
  "-s" "0" "-D" "-A" "-T" "$i.esp.srt" \
  "--track-order" "0:0,0:1,1:0,2:0"
done

find . -type f ! -name "*.mkv" ! -name "*.sh" -delete

for files in *.mkv
do
 mv "$files" "${files%.mkv}.mp4"
done 

notify-send -t 2000 "Fin de la conversión"
```

This latter part, merge the mp4 file with the srt files.

Comment: It looks pretty clean already, doing the minimum. Maybe you could add `&&` at the end of each command to handle errors better. Also you could write if statements more bash style, just for fun (e.g. `[[ -z "$id" ]] && echo "Warning" && continue`)

Comment: Question is probably better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do much to change it. The major thing is I tidied up the `mkvmerge` call -- too many quotes looks very messy:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -iname "*.mp4" | 
while IFS= read -r f; do
    id=$(sed -n 's/.*.S\([0-9]\+\)E\([0-9]\+\)..*/\1x\2/p' <<< "$f" | sed 's/^0\+//')

    if [ -z "$id" ]; then
        echo "Warning! there's no match for $f"
    else
        for srt in *"$id"*; do
            newName=$(sed 's/ (English).srt/.mp4/g' <<< "$srt")
            mv "$f" "$newName"
        done
    fi
done 

for i in *" (Español (España)).srt"; do
    iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "${i%%" (Español (España)).srt"}.esp.srt" &&
    rm "$i"
done
#sleep 0.5

for i in *".mp4"; do
    i=${i%.mp4} 
    mkvmerge -o "$i.mkv" \
        --language 1:eng -a 1 -d 0 -S -T "$i.mp4" \
        --language 0:eng -s 0 -D -A -T "$i (English).srt" \
        --language 0:spa -s 0 -D -A -T "$i.esp.srt" \
        --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:0,2:0
done

find . -type f ! -name "*.mkv" ! -name "*.sh" -delete

for f in *.mkv; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.mkv}.mp4"
done 

notify-send -t 2000 "Fin de la conversión"
```